# Laravel to send email for logging instead of writing to storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've looked through the documentation and can't find a way to change the logging for any errors, which normally write to /app/storage/logs/logs/log-apache2handler-xxxx-xx-xx.txt

but on the production server, I want any of those to be emailed to me instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I still log the error, and if it's production, send an email with the exception:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
Log::error($exception);

if (Config::getEnvironment() == 'production')
{
    $data = array('exception' => $exception);
    Mail::send('emails.error', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from($email_app);
        $message->to(Config::get('settings.error_email'))->subject(Config::get('settings.app_name') . ' Error');
    });
    Log::info('Error Email sent to ' . Config::get('settings.error_email'));
    return Response::view('errors.500', array(), 500);
}
});
```

Comment: What about using App::environment() instead of Config::getEnvironment() ?

Comment: Why when I do this its sends me a random number of the same mail ?

Comment: To make it look the same as in the log, it's better to force cast the exception to string.  $data = array('exception' => (string)$exception);

Answer (score 5):

Due Laravel uses the Monolog library internally, I think it is a better solution to use the intended log handlers. So every uncatched exception and manual calls of Log will be send to your mail address.

**if you're using mail()**

Add NativeMailerHandler to your app/start/global.php:

```
$logFile = 'log-'.php_sapi_name().'.txt';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
Log::getMonolog()->pushHandler(
    new Monolog\Handler\NativeMailerHandler(
        'to@domain.de',
        '[Log] Some Subject',
        'from@domain.de'
        Logger::ERROR, // set minimal log lvl for mail
        true, // bubble to next handler?
        70 // max column width in your mail
    )
);
```

**if you've configured Laravel SMTP Mailing**

Add SwiftMailerHandler to your app/start/global.php:

(Swift Mailer is also used internally by Laravel)

```
$logFile = 'log-'.php_sapi_name().'.txt';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
Log::getMonolog()->pushHandler(
    new Monolog\Handler\SwiftMailerHandler(
        Mail::getSwiftMailer(),
        Swift_Message::newInstance('[Log] Some Subject')->setFrom('from@domain.de')->setTo('to@domain.de'),
        Logger::ERROR, // set minimal log lvl for mail
        true // bubble to next handler?
    )
);
```

Add environment check as described in the other post if you want to. For many other handlers, also have a look at https://github.com/seldaek/monolog

Answer (score 2):

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    //Log::error($exception);
    // send email
});
```

Check the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors

Basically it is up to you what logic to put in the handler. I think it may also be possible to create a separate global.php for production, without putting if-else statements to find out which environment you are on.

Comment: Definitely better to go this route if you want an email. Be wary of destroying your inbox if the same error pops up a lot. You don't want 893475934 unread emails all of sudden.

Answer (score 2):

use package like

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's composer.json file to require dinesh/bugonemail.

Or visit

http://dineshrabara.github.io/bugonemail/